# My 2-year-old won't sleep at night

Tags: toddler, sleep, bedtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a 2-year-old back to sleep in the middle of the night](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/getting-a-2-year-old-back-to-sleep-in-the-middle-of-the-night)

My 2-year-old just started 2 weeks ago to not sleep at night like he used to. I've tried keeping him up later and I let him get himself tired out and nothing has changed. I did what the doctors said to do with him and nothing has changed with him. It's still the same, he will fall asleep at 8pm or 930pm and be up at 12 am and then stay up yelling and screaming and nothing I do helps him fall asleep, but when 8am comes around he falls asleep and then can sleep all day until 5 pm or longer. Please help! I'm in really bad need, the endless sleep less night are getting to me.

Comment: Can you post something like a log of what his days look like?  Are you letting him sleep 8 a.m. to 5 p.m. or am I reading your question wrong?

Comment: he falls a sleep at 8am and if i would let him sleep he would sleep until 5pm or longer

Comment: Hi Mary, and welcome to the site! Sleep problems with toddlers have been addressed in [several other posts already](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep+toddler). I think [this one](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/getting-a-2-year-old-back-to-sleep-in-the-middle-of-the-night) and maybe [this](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/how-do-you-prevent-a-toddler-from-waking-too-early) could be particularly useful to you?

Comment: @mary - if that's the case you may have a case of day-night confusion on your hands.  The solution is usually to limit day sleep and move it to an appropriate time.  I bet he got overtired as you tried to keep him up later, too.  For a while you'll have overtiredness on your hands from the transition but once that shakes itself out he should be able to go back to similar patterns as those he had before.  Note that sleep needs often change around 2 and 2.5 years old as far as I've read, so maybe he needs less sleep now.